# Least Permission for day-to-day administration of Exchange

Tags: permissions, exchange-2010

We're in the middle of migrating to Exchange 2010. When it's done, our SA in charge of Exchange will be moving to a non-technical position within the department. We're taking this opportunity to review Exchange administration procedures, which raises the question:

If the Exchange admin's sole responsibility is managing MS Exchange, does that person need an account that's a member of Domain Administrators? If not, are there any documents available describing least-permission for SAs managing Exchange?

Comment: Is there any additional information I can provide you so we can make the answer appropriately?

Comment: Well, I haven't implemented this yet, and likely won't for a few weeks. I'm not going to accept an answer until I've tested it and verified that it meets my needs. Don't worry, you'll get your little green check mark eventually :)

Comment: No worries, I'm just not a fan of loose ends. :)

Comment: I take it all seems well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll find Exchange 2010's [RBAC](http://www.shudnow.net/2009/04/17/exchange-2010-permissions-and-security-groups/) (Role Based Access Control) a PERFECT fit for the situation you're facing. It allows you to define levels of groups and roles responsible for certain tasks within Exchange, without exposing them to additional permissions within Active Directory itself.

Here's the [TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298183.aspx) on RBAC for you to read as well.